# How to handle Special json POST with Flutter

Tags: arrays, json, flutter

I have a JSON POST that I'm sending from my Flutter app as soon in the below code:

```
// class connecting value from the textfield to database with json
class LoginProfile {
  int id;

String CardNumber;
String ExpiryDate;
String ExpiryYear;
String VerifyCode;


  LoginProfile({this.id = 0,this.CardNumber
    ,this.ExpiryDate,this.ExpiryYear});

  factory LoginProfile.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> map) {
    return LoginProfile(
        id: map["id"],
        CardNumber: map["CardNumber"],ExpiryDate: map["ExpiryDate"],ExpiryYear: map["ExpiryYear"]
        );
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    return {"id": id,"CardNumber": CardNumber
      ,"ExpiryDate": ExpiryDate,"ExpiryYear": ExpiryYear};
  }

  @override
  String toString() {
    return 'Profile{id: $id, "CardNumber": CardNumber
      ,"ExpiryDate": ExpiryDate,"ExpiryYear": ExpiryYear}';
  }
}

Future<bool> createProfile(LoginProfile data) async {
      response = await client.post(
        "$baseUrl",
        headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8'},
        body: loginProfileToJson(data),
      );
      if (response.statusCode == 201) {
        return true;
      } else {
        print(response.body);
}
}
```

I am meant POST my JSON as below:

```
{
"Registration": {
 "CardNumber":"5105105105105100",
 "ExpiryDate":"11",
 "ExpiryYear":"2023",
 "VerifyCode":"123"
 }
 }
```

For some reason, I'm unable to make this work and I need to POST "Registration" as the object like it looks above.

Comment: encode your json data

Comment: How? And Where?

Answer (score 0):

Try with jsonEncode

```
Future<bool> createProfile(LoginProfile data) async {
      response = await client.post(
        "$baseUrl",
        headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8'},
        body: jsonEncode(loginProfileToJson(data)),
      );
      if (response.statusCode == 201 || response.statusCode == 200) {
        return true;
      } else {
        print(response.body);
}
```

Comment: How do I parse "Registration"?

Comment: yeah you will parse registration

Comment: Can you please edit your answer base on my question?

Comment: please have a look, updated `createProfile ` section

Comment: I used the above code that you added but I didn't get any response.